# Why my code did not get into [super init] function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class-cluster

There are three class `Question`,`Choice`and `Blank`,and `Question` is the super class of `Choice` and `Blank`.

Then, I write some methods as follows:

```
- (instancetype)initWithQuestionType:(NSString *)questionType
{
    NSLog(@"**class:%@",[self class]);
    if([self isMemberOfClass:[Question class]])
    {
        self = nil;
        if([questionType isEqualToString:@"choice"])
        {
            NSLog(@"--class:%@",[self class]);
            self = [[Choice alloc] initWithQuestionType:questionType];
            NSLog(@"++class:%@",[self class]);
        }
        else
        {
            self = [[Blank alloc] initWithQuestionType:questionType];
        }

        return self;
    }

    return [super init];
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    NSLog(@"Init!");

    return [self initWithQuestionType:@"unKnow"];
}
```

and then:

```
Question *question = [[Question alloc] initWithQuestionType:@"choice"];
```

the output is：

```
2015-10-16 20:58:50.278 initSample[3687:161396] **class:Question
2015-10-16 20:58:50.279 initSample[3687:161396] --class:(null)
2015-10-16 20:58:50.279 initSample[3687:161396] **class:Choice
2015-10-16 20:58:50.280 initSample[3687:161396] ++class:Choice
```

and I can't understand why `[super init]` did not be executed?

Comment: Because `if([self isMemberOfClass:[Question class]])` is true and it returns self before it gets to return `[super init];`, That was a wild stab in the dark. Try changing `isMemberOfClass` to `isKindOfClass:`

Comment: Which class is this code in?

Comment: @CalebKleveter What difference would that make?

Comment: @CalebKleveter Yes, you are incorrect. The order of the methods in the source file is irrelevant.

Comment: @CalebKleveter I'm not sure whether you're being sarcastic or not.

Comment: @Popeye, I am not being sarcastic.

Comment: the `[super init];` probably will be invoked if the first if-else statement evaluated as `FALSE` in the `-initWithQuestionType:` method; but because your log line in your instance's `–init` method (not in the super's) therefore that line will be called when the `[[Question alloc] init];` or `[Question new];` performed, but I'm not sure about your question, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `[super init]` method is being called:

1. `[Question initWithQuestionType]` is called.
2. The first `if` is true, so it's entered.
3. The question type is `"choice"` so `[Choice initWithQuestionType:]` is called.
4. As `Choice` does not override `-initWithQuestionType:`, this will call `[Question initWithQuestionType:]` again.
5. This time the `if` is false, so it's not entered, and `[super init]` is being called.

This is being shown in your log messages (add an another log call before the `[super init]` method, to prove this).

However it's a very confusing and difficult to maintain factory method, and it's much easier to use a class factory method, as below. That way your `init` methods will be much more straight-forward and easier to maintain.

```
+ (Question *)questionWithType:(NSString *)type
{
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"choice"])
        return [[Choice alloc] init];
    else
        return [[Blank alloc] init];
}
```

Also consider using an `enum` to represent the type, rather than a string (quicker/more efficient).

Comment: While this may be useful info it does not answer the question.

Comment: @l00phole it would probably be better if you explain why it is completely incorrect instead of just saying it is completely incorrect. I currently agree with `rmaddy` but I am open to change.

Comment: @rmaddy OK, taken a stab at it.

Comment: Yes,`[super init]` method is being called. And the method being called is belong to Question's super class. I can't understand why.

Comment: @lxyzk You have created very complex code that is difficult to understand.  There is no need to do this; just use the class-level factory method approach as shown in my answer.  That way the implementation of the `init` methods becomes trivial.

Comment: @l00phole Very grateful for your advice